# Why is Fantomex the only X-Force member to have telepathic dampening plates?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-force

A few times in the current run of Uncanny X-Force we see all the team disabled by a telepath, except for Fantomex.  His usual lament in these cases is "Why am I the only one with telepathic dampening plates?"  I think this is a very good question - why is he the only one?  It seems like a very useful defense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Fantomex is the only person who is using his particular ceramic telepathic dampening plates on the Marvel Earth #616.**

The origin of the technology is likely part of the anti-mutant development done by the intelligent bacteria, [Sublime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_%28Marvel_Comics%29) and its Weapon Plus program. Considering Charles Xavier is the premier telepath and scientist regarding telepathic tech, the fact he has not developed a comparable tool implies:

- the Weapon Plus technology is highly sophisticated and cutting edge experimental
- The technology requires very unique components unavailable to the rest of the Earth #616.
- the technology may be linked to the very specialized nervous system of Fantomex

It is likely a variant could be created with sufficient time, expertise and willingness on the part of Fantomex to share the technology and assuming there are no unique components.

[image]

There have already been limited tools designed in the Marvel Universe that offer limited resistance to telepathy including the helmets of Magneto and the Juggernaut. Strong electromagnetic fields have also been known to affect telepathy and is why Magneto altered the Earth's magnetic field to limit Xavier's telepathic range and ability.